# ROS unable to function after fuerte update (due to python)

Tags: ros, ros-comm, roscore, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since finding myself victim of the infamous [multi-master roslaunch problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/36600/how-to-tell-remote-machines-not-to-start-separate-roscores-when-using-roslaunch-fuerte-regression/) I updated my fuerte installation.

Now nothing works anymore.

```
erupter@FCD-04-Ubuntu:~/Apps/ROS$ roscore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 222, in main
    uuid = rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(options.run_id, options.wait_for_master)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/roslaunch/rlutil.py", line 170, in get_or_generate_uuid
    param_server = rosgraph.Master('/roslaunch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rosgraph/masterapi.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._reinit(master_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/rosgraph/masterapi.py", line 118, in _reinit
    self.handle = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(self.master_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1549, in __init__
    raise IOError, "unsupported XML-RPC protocol"
IOError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol
```

Tried compiling ros_comm from source, it's now 1.8.15 yet it still provokes the same error.
Which at this point I suppose has something to do with python rather than ros...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53254/ros-unable-to-function-after-fuerte-update-(due-to-python)/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the culprit: these errors spawn if, for some reason, the ROS_MASTER_URI is malformed.
In my case it was something like

```
htpp://hostname:11311/
```

notice the ***htpp***.
Correcting this everything gets back to working.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3